# Add a second (or multiple) pictures to a CV

Tags: floats, moderncv

I plan to add a second image to my CV, a QR code for instance, in addition to a profile picture, as it is shown below in the example from the web. The webpage doesn't offer any latex code, though.

In ModernCV, there's the `\photo` command, which sets exactly one photo. How can I add a second one?

[image]

Comment: Can you add the code for this CV so that we can try it out without writing a CV from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eso-pic` and overlay the photo:

```
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\AtPageUpperMyleft[1]{\AtPageUpperLeft{%
 \put(\LenToUnit{1.5cm},\LenToUnit{-3.5cm}){#1}%
 }}%

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
\AtPageUpperMyleft{\fboxsep1.5pt\fcolorbox{red}{white}%
{\includegraphics[width=60pt,height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{ctanlion}}}
}
```

Adjust the dimension `1.5cm` and `-3.5cm` as suitable.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{red}
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}
%% ↓
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\AtPageUpperMyleft[1]{\AtPageUpperLeft{%
 \put(\LenToUnit{1.5cm},\LenToUnit{-3.5cm}){#1}%
 }}%

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
\AtPageUpperMyleft{\fboxsep1.5pt\fcolorbox{red}{white}%
{\includegraphics[width=60pt,height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{ctanlion}}}
}


% personal data
\name{}{}
\title{}
\address{123 Main Street}{Anytown, USA 20192}
\phone[mobile]{(555) 555-5555}
\email{dasasd@gmail.com}
\homepage{www.asdasd.com}
\social[linkedin]{asdasdasd}
\social[github]{asdasdasd}
\photo{logo}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Selected Projects}

\end{document}
```

[image]